# Avoiding off-by-one errors when removing columns based on indices in a python list

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

I have a target file called `TARGFILE` of the form:

```
10001000020002002001100100200000111
10201001020000120210101100110010011
02010010200000011100012021001012021
00102000012001202100101202100111010
```

My idea here was to leave this as a string, and use slicing in python to remove the indices.

The removal will occur based on a list of integers called `INDICES` like so:

```
[1, 115654, 115655, 115656, 2, 4, 134765, 134766, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 17659, 92573, 30, 32, 88932, 33, 35, 37, 110463, 38, 18282, 46, 18458, 48, 51, 54]
```

I want to remove every position of *every* line in `TARGFILE` that matches with `INDICES`. For instance, the first digit in `INDICES` is 1, so the first column of `TARGFILE` containing 1,1,0,0 would be removed. However, I am weary of doing this incorrectly due to off-by-one errors and changing index positions if everything is not removed at the same time.

Thus, a solution that removed every column from each row at the same time would likely be both much faster and safer than using a nested loop, but I am unsure of how to code this.

My code so far is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
SRC_FILES=open('YCP.txt', 'r')

for line in SRC_FILES:
    EUR_YRI_ADM=line.strip('\n')
    EUR,YRI,ADM=EUR_YRI_ADM.split(' ')
    ADMFO=open(ADM, 'r')
    lines=ADMFO.readlines()
    INDICES=[int(val) for val in lines[0].split()]
    TARGFILE=open(EUR, 'r')
```

It seems to me that a solution using `enumerate` might be possible, but I have not found it, and that might be suboptimal in the first place...

EDIT: in response to concerns about memory: the longest lines are ~180,000 items, but I should be able to get this into memory without a problem, I have access to a cluster.

Comment: do you expect to have more than a hundred thousand columns in `TARGFILE`? do you want to open and read file `ADM` during each loop or read it once before the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the simplicity of Peter's answer, even though it's currently off-by-one.  My thought is that you can get rid of the index-shifting problem, by sorting INDICES, and doing the process from the back to the front.  That led to remove_indices1, which is really inefficient.  I think 2 is better, but simplest is 3, which is Peter's answer.

I may do timing in a bit for some large numbers, but my intuition says that my remove_indices2 will be faster than Peter's remove_indices3 if INDICES is very sparse.  (Because you don't have to iterate over each character, but only over the indices that are being deleted.)

BTW - If you can sort INDICES once, then you don't need to make the local copy to sort/reverse, but I didn't know if you could do that.

```
rows = [
    '0000000001111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667',
    '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890',
    ]

def remove_nth_character(row,n):
    return row[:n-1] + row[n:]

def remove_indices1(row,indices):
    local_indices = indices[:]
    retval = row
    local_indices.sort()
    local_indices.reverse()
    for i in local_indices:
        retval = remove_nth_character(retval,i)
    return retval

def remove_indices2(row,indices):
    local_indices = indices[:]
    local_indices.sort()
    local_indices.reverse()
    front = row
    chunks = []
    for i in local_indices:
        chunks.insert(0,front[i:])
        front = front[:i-1]
    chunks.insert(0,front)
    return "".join(chunks)

def remove_indices3(row,indices):
    return ''.join(c for i,c in enumerate(row) if i+1 not in indices)

indices = [1,11,4,54,33,20,7]

for row in rows:
    print remove_indices1(row,indices)
print ""
for row in rows:
    print remove_indices2(row,indices)
print ""
for row in rows: 
    print remove_indices3(row,indices)
```

*EDIT:  Adding timing info, plus a new winner!*

As I suspected, my algorithm (remove_indices2) wins when there aren't many indices to remove.  It turns out that the enumerate-based one, though, gets worse even faster as there are more indices to remove.  Here's the timing code (bigrows rows have 210000 characters):

```
bigrows = []
for row in rows:
    bigrows.append(row * 30000)

for indices_len in [10,100,1000,10000,100000]:
    print "indices len: %s" % indices_len
    indices = range(indices_len)
    #for func in [remove_indices1,remove_indices2,remove_indices3,remove_indices4]:
    for func in [remove_indices2,remove_indices4]:
        start = time.time()
        for row in bigrows:
            func(row,indices)
        print "%s: %s" % (func.__name__,(time.time() - start))
```

And here are the results:

```
indices len: 10
remove_indices1: 0.0187089443207
remove_indices2: 0.00184297561646
remove_indices3: 1.40601491928
remove_indices4: 0.692481040955
indices len: 100
remove_indices1: 0.0974130630493
remove_indices2: 0.00125503540039
remove_indices3: 7.92742991447
remove_indices4: 0.679095029831
indices len: 1000
remove_indices1: 0.841033935547
remove_indices2: 0.00370812416077
remove_indices3: 73.0718669891
remove_indices4: 0.680690050125
```

So, why does 3 do so much worse?  Well, it turns out that the `in` operator isn't efficient on a list.  It's got to iterate through all of the list items to check.  `remove_indices4` is just 3 but converting indices to a set first, so the inner loop can do a fast hash-lookup, instead of iterating through the list:

```
def remove_indices4(row,indices):
    indices_set = set(indices)
    return ''.join(c for i,c in enumerate(row) if i+1 not in indices_set)
```

And, as I originally expected, this does better than my algorithm for high densities:

```
indices len: 10
remove_indices2: 0.00230097770691
remove_indices4: 0.686790943146
indices len: 100
remove_indices2: 0.00113391876221
remove_indices4: 0.665997982025
indices len: 1000
remove_indices2: 0.00296902656555
remove_indices4: 0.700706005096
indices len: 10000
remove_indices2: 0.074893951416
remove_indices4: 0.679219007492
indices len: 100000
remove_indices2: 6.65899395943
remove_indices4: 0.701599836349
```

If you've got fewer than 10000 indices to remove, 2 is fastest (even faster if you do the indices sort/reverse once outside the function).  But, if you want something that is pretty stable in time, no matter how many indices, use 4.

Comment: This 4th solution is reusable (I in fact have 2 TARGFILES, not one), is accurate, is invertible (can keep or remove the word NOT) and is extremely fast. Thank you very much for your efforts. I will try to learn as much as I can from this answer.

Comment: Great answer John - I love the benchmarks and the use of `set` to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can see would be something like:

```
>>> for line in TARGFILE:
...     print ''.join(c for i,c in enumerate(line) if (i+1) not in INDICES)
...
100000200020020100200001
100010200001202010110001
010102000000111021001021
000000120012021012100110
```

(Substituting print for writing to your output file etc)

This relies on being able to load each line into memory which may or may not be reasonable given your data.

Edit: explaination:

The first line is straightforward:

```
>>> for line in TARGFILE:
```

Just iterates through each line in `TARGFILE`. The second line is a bit more complex:

- `''.join(...)` concatenates a list of strings together with an empty joiner (`''`). `join` is often used with a comma like: `','.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) == 'a,b,c'`, but here we just want to join each item to the next.
- `enumerate(...)` takes an interable and returns pairs of `(index, item)` for each item in the iterable. For example `enumerate('abc') == (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')`

So the line says,

> Join together each character of line whose index are not found in INDICES

However, as John pointed out, Python indexes are zero base, so we add 1 to the value from enumerate.

Comment: heh.  He was worried about off by one errors, and your solution is off by one.  Needs to be "if i+1 not in INDICES".  Otherwise, though, I like the simplicity of this.

Comment: Hi John and @PeterGibson - I am implementing this now at which time I will accept an answer - I like this as well though I am not entirely sure how it is actually functioning.

Comment: @VincentLaufer - I know you've accepted this answer, but please make the `set()` modification I mention in my answer to your code.  It'll improve your performance significantly.

Answer (score 0):

The script I ended up using is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def remove_indices(row,indices):
    indices_set = set(indices)
    return ''.join(c for i,c in enumerate(row) if (i+1) in indices_set)

SRC_FILES=open('YCP2.txt', 'r')

CEUDIR='/USER/ScriptsAndLists/LAMP/LAMPLDv1.1/IN/aps/4bogdan/omni/CEU/PARSED/'
YRIDIR='/USER/ScriptsAndLists/LAMP/LAMPLDv1.1/IN/aps/4bogdan/omni/YRI/PARSED/'
i=0
for line in SRC_FILES:
        i+=1
    EUR_YRI_ADM=line.strip('\n')
        EUR,YRI,ADM=EUR_YRI_ADM.split('\t')
        ADMFO=open(ADM, 'r')


        lines=ADMFO.readlines()
        INDICES=[int(val) for val in lines[0].split()]
        INDEXSORT=sorted(INDICES, key=int)

        EURF=open(EUR, 'r')
        EURFOUT=open(CEUDIR + 'chr' + str(i) + 'anc.hap.txt' , 'a')
        for haplotype in EURF:
                TRIMLINE=remove_indices(haplotype, INDEXSORT)
                EURFOUT.write(TRIMLINE + '\n')
        EURFOUT.close()

        AFRF=open(YRI, 'r')
        AFRFOUT=open(YRIDIR + 'chr' + str(i) + 'anc.hap.txt' , 'a')
        for haplotype2 in AFRF:
                TRIMLINE=remove_indices(haplotype2, INDEXSORT)
                AFRFOUT.write(TRIMLINE + '\n')
        AFRFOUT.close()
```